# Possible to have a combobox reflect SQL data based on a selection in a datagridview that is connected to a DataSource?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview with records with given data from a datasource connected to a SQL Database. What I want to do is to select a row and have a combobox pull related data for a given field from the datagridview and have it populate the combobox. What I want to do is have the combobox be filtered by a field in the datagridview.

I am able to write a SQL statement to pull ALL data from a field in SQL and populate the combobox but I cannot get that to correlate with a given field from the datagridview and I do not think that is possible but I could be wrong.

Anything helps!

Comment: I am sure this is possible, could you edit your question and show us your code so we can help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This question does not have any kind of detail for others to help. We are not involved in this project like you are and have no idea what you are trying to do other than an extremely vague description.

Comment: As the commenters above have stated, this is possible, but we can't give a concrete answer without seeing some code.  A way to accomplish this goal would be to override the RowSelected event on your datagridview and then you can update the value of the combobox from there.

Comment: @samyap I am unable to show code beause it is a program I am unfamiliar with and it is quite large. Basically, I want to create a combobox and have that combobox display Part Numbers for a given Part Description for a selected row in the datagridview. The issue is I want all the Part numbers for that given part description to pull from my SQL server, not from what is in my datagridview. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Kris it does, I would recommend doing it from the datagridview, but my process from above still holds true, you will need to implement one of the click events for the datagridview and then you can make any db calls and combobox value updates from that event method body